# Cannot connect to an ASP.NET Core 6 application running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am running an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project inside a Docker container.

I use the watch command to run the application, which I know is running inside the container, because I ran a curl command in the container. Also volumes are correctly mapped, because whenever I make changes they are picked up judging form the container logs.

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    ports:
     - 5048:5048
    working_dir: /backend
    volumes:
     - .:/backend:cached
    command: sh -c "dotnet dev-certs https && dotnet watch"
```

I get an error message saying The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. in browser.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?

Comment: Using http://localhost:5048

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by changing the urls for the hot reload profile in launch settings from http(s)://localhost:port to http(s)://0.0.0.0:port. Dotnet watch does not seems work work well with the localhost url.